# Unable to Create a New Project in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I teach programming classes using Visual Studio 2012 express.  In the last week three students ran into a problem while creating a new C++ project and hitting finish it just loops them back to the create new project screen.  All students had Visual Studio 2012 Express installed and running on their computers for several weeks before they encountered this problem.  All three students are running Windows 8.  Does anyone know why this is happening or how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio?

Comment: did you solve the problem?